# Django migrate app zero does not drop tables

Tags: sql-server, django, migration

I understand that all migrations applied to an app can be reversed using "migrate <app_name> zero". In the migration folder for the app, there are two migration files. However the below shows "No migrations to apply". And afterward when trying to run "migrate <app_name>" the database is returning an error saying that there is already an object of the name.

Can someone help me understand what is happening here? Why is "migrate <app_name> zero" not seeing the two migrations that need to be reversed.

```
C:\Users\...\mysite>python manage.py migrate awards zero
Operations to perform:
  Unapply all migrations: awards
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.

C:\Users\...\mysite>python manage.py migrate awards
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: awards
Running migrations:
  Applying awards.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\sql_server\pyodbc\base.py", line 553, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42S01', "[42S01] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]There is already an object named 'awards_student' in the database. (2714) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

Thank you!

Comment: Are there new migration files under `migrations/` in the app? (i.e. `0001_... 0002_...)

Comment: Seem like Django doesn't think those migrations have been applied in the first place. What is the output from `python manage.py showmigrations awards`?

Comment: The migrations are in the migrations/ directory as expected:

`C:\Users\...\mysite>python manage.py showmigrations awards
awards
 [ ] 0001_initial
 [ ] 0002_auto_20210319_1850
`

Comment: Late reply to @IainShelvington: 

`C:\Users\p...\mysite>python manage.py showmigrations awards awards [ ] 0001_initial [ ] 0002_auto_20210319_1850 [ ] 0003_auto_20210414_1320
`
 You are correct that Django thinks that the migrations have not been applied. But the table exists in the database, and the schema change specified in migration 0002 also seems to have been made. Unclear how Django has marked these migrations as not having been applied, even though the underlying changes seem to have occurred. 

Fixed the problem by deleting the table and running the migrations again.